# access value class module in another sub

Tags: excel, class, vba, global-variables

I need some help with the following. I made a class module called CMpos:

```
Public secId As String
```

Then in a module the following code which is working well:

```
   Sub testclass()

rijaantal_LenDump = Application.CountA(Sheets("Len_Dump").Range("A:A"))
kolomaantal_LenDump = Application.CountA(Sheets("Len_Dump").Range("1:1"))

Sheets("Len_Dump").Select
positions = Sheets("Len_Dump").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rijaantal_LenDump, kolomaantal_LenDump))


kolomSecID = 8

Dim isc As New Collection

For i = 1 To rijaantal_LenDump
Set psecs = New CMpos
psecs.secId = CStr(positions(i, 8))
If Not Exists(isc, psecs.secId) Then isc.Add psecs, psecs.secId
Next i

Debug.Print isc.Count

MsgBox isc(8).secId

End Sub
```

Now I would like to access the value in the class moldule from another sub but here I get an error on line MsgBox isc(8).secId (type mismatch). I made a Globale Variable in a seperate module with the line Public isc As Collection.

```
Sub hjhk()
Call testclass
Dim isc As CMpos

Set isc = New Collection


MsgBox isc(8).secId
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Amir

Comment: `isc` in `testClass` goes out of scope as soon ans that sub ends. You need to declare it as a global variable outside of `testClass`.  Or turn `testClass` into a function which returns the collection it creates.

Comment: Hi Tim, i tried that. I declared isc as a global variable outside testclass as follows: public isc as Collection. Something else is wrong.

Comment: In `hjhk` you're creating a brand-new collection object `isc` with local scope. This has no content, so trying to access `isc(8)` is going to fail...

Comment: Ok but how can acces the collection made in sub testclass in sub hjhk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim isc as Collection 'global variable

Sub testclass()

    Dim psecs as CMpos

    Set isc = New Collection 'isc refers to the global variable,
                             '  so no need to declare it here

    For i = 1 To 8
        Set psecs = New CMpos
        psecs.secId = "Test-" & i
        isc.Add psecs, psecs.secId
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    testClass
    Debug.Print isc(8).secId 'sic is declared as global, so no need to declare/create
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, it works now. Could you also explain the need for:    Dim psecs as CMpos and Set isc = New Collection. I used -> Dim isc As New Collection. Why is this not working and what are the differences? Thanks!!